# Error while deleting Netbeans, NetBeans leaves in windows 10

Tags: java, netbeans

[image]

dear collegues.

while removing neatbeans, I got an exception like this. I don't know how to overcome with it. I I click on Yes, netBeans asks to uninstall the system, While clicking on Uninstall, the system removes, in actually the netbeans leaves.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the netbeans installation. You should create a bug report at apache netbeans

Comment: Jens, hello. I have created a bug in netbeans, but no response. https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/4530    I do not know what to do now.